# Can't access Windows EC2 instance from public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop

I have a aws Windows Server 2016 instance with Jenkins setup. I can see jenkins is up and running when I browse to localhost:8080 on the EC2 instance through remote desktop protocol but cannot access it from outside or its ip (using x.x.x.x:8080).

when I try the x.x.x.x I can't even see the default IIS page showing up.

In security config i have opened port 8080 for Custom TCP Rule,

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score -1):

Even I had the same issue. That must be firewall issue on your EC2. Try closing Firewall and recheck.

Comment: Tried doing that too. Still no luck

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution. Go to your RDP  and open windows firewall. Goto advance setting. On right you would see add rule option click it create a new role with type port and give port number 8080 for TCP. That would do it for you!